# Extract download progress from curl output

Tags: sed, curl

I'm trying to extract the download progress of a file that's being retrieved by `curl`.

I tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
curl --progress-bar http://127.0.0.1/test.tar.bz2 -o test.tar.bz2 2>/dev/stdout | sed -r 's/[# ]//g;s/^/#/g'
```

The `sed` expression seems to be fine though:

```
$ echo '########                      10.2%' | sed -r 's/[# ]//g;s/^/#/g'
#10.2%
```

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expeted output?

Comment: I had thought that curl might not output progress bars to file, but it appears it does. @terdon, don't confuse stderr with "screen". Just because `isatty(2)` is often true, it doesn't mean they're the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `sed` works on *lines* so it doesn't do anything until the first `\n` is reached and that doesn't happen until your command is finished. You can get around this by exchanging `\r`s with `\n`s:

```
$ curl --progress-bar http://127.0.0.1/test.tar.bz2 -o test.tar.bz2 2>&1 | 
   tr $'\r' $'\n' | sed -r 's/[# ]+/#/g;'
```

This, however, brings you up against buffering, `sed` will now act on groups of lines. The final solution I hacked together was to redirect the error to a file and then deal with that file:

```
$ curl --progress-bar http://127.0.0.1/test.tar.bz2 -o test.tar.bz2 2>er
$ while :; do 
    echo -ne "$(tr $'\r' $'\n' < er | tail -n 1 | sed -r 's/^[# ]+/#/;')\r"; 
  done
```

The command above will parse the error file (`er`) and print the result with an `\r` making it update constantly. You will need to break out of it manually.

*Suggestion from an anonymous user:* You can also put `stdbuf -oL` in front of `tr` and `sed` thus modifying the buffering behaviour of those commands.

Comment: Will sed's unbuffered mode work here? (since it seems you're trying to emulate just that)

Comment: @user2064000 I don't think so. The first issue will still be there and the buffering is more an issue of the pipe passing the data to `sed` than sed itself. I can't get it to work in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Try perl:

```
curl --progress-bar http://127.0.0.1/test.tar.bz2 -o test.tar.bz2 2>&1 | perl -015 -n -e 'print "$1\n" if (/[#]* ([\d]+)/);'
```

where:

- 2>&1 assigns stderr to where ever stdout is going which in this case is a pipe to perl
- -015 sets the input record separator to carriage return (octal 15)
- -e is a line of code, in this case one that skips any leading #'s and extracts a subsequent integer into $1 which is printed whenever
  this extraction succeeds.
- -n wraps the lines provided with -e in "while(<>){}" which reads the input record-by-record until EOF, where we have arranged for each record to be separated by CR with -0